# Need to Automate PPTP connectivity from Linux to Windows

Tags: windows, linux, vpn, cron

I'm in need of setting up cron-based VPN connectivity from Ubuntu "Jaunty" to a Windows-based VPN over PPTP for incremental DB synchronization.  Using the default Network Manager and PPTP module everything seems to work fine.  However, I have 2 issues:

1)  Despite checking "Use this only for resources", I still lose my local internet connection and am routed through their servers.

2) As a result of 1 I have need to automate connecting to and disconnecting from the VPN in order to perform various tasks as the machine is at the office and I am not.

Much of the information I'm finding on PPTPing from Linux to Windows involves the use of GUI Network Manager, etc.  However, I need to perform these steps from the command line for the sake of automation.  Can anyone point me to a quality bit of documentation for this specific case?

Best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://pptpclient.sourceforge.net/
I think this site has everything that you need :)

Comment: Fair enough, but that site also has *much more* than what I need.  I was hoping someone could provide some more direct info.  Thanks for the post though.